# MBR bootstrap code creation

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mbr

What does creating a new partition (using disk utility like `fdisk`) really do? Does it create only Partition Table or also the MBR bootstrap code?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) a program should do one thing and do it well. If a given tool is supposed to modify partition tables then it shouldn't bother itself with modifying bootstrap code (or creating filesystem etc.).

Of course there are bloated tools with all the bells and whistles, `fdisk` is not one of them. You will find my analysis of its behavior down below. It proves **it's entirely possible to create a new partition while leaving the MBR bootstrap code unaltered.**

I don't know all the disk utilities on every platform. This answer is intended to cover Linux `fdisk` utility only.

---

### The case of `fdisk`

Testbed: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, `fdisk` from `util-linux 2.27.1`.

---

#### 1. File of zeros

I created an empty file with

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=mydisk bs=1M count=1
```

Then I run `fdisk mydisk` and added a single partition from the sector `63` to `2047`, I wrote the partition table.

The output of `hexdump -C mydisk`:

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  bb 50 d8 1d 00 00 00 01  |.........P......|
000001c0  01 00 83 20 20 00 3f 00  00 00 c1 07 00 00 00 00  |...  .?.........|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00100000
```

As you can see the first nonzero byte is at `0x1b8`; the last one is at `0x1ff`. Compare this to the [structure of a modern standard MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Disk_partitioning) and you will see it's the fragment from *disk signature* to *boot signature*. I also set the bootable flag afterwards but it also had no impact on the bootstrap code. **No meaningful bootstrap code appeared, it won't boot.**

---

#### 2. MBR with garbage, invalid signature

Having the same file I overwrote its MBR with garbage:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=mydisk bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

And I made sure there is no boot signature (the proper one would be `0xAA55` little endian, I used `0x1234`):

```
echo -ne "\x34\x12" | dd of=mydisk bs=1 count=2 seek=510 conv=notrunc
```

Then I created a partition as before. All the garbage was overwritten by `fdisk` and the `hexdump -C mydisk` output was exactly as before. **The bootstrap code area was zeroed, it won't boot.**

---

#### 3. MBR with garbage, valid signature

The same file. Writing garbage again:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=mydisk bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

This time I set proper boot signature (`0xAA55`, little endian):

```
echo -ne "\x55\xAA" | dd of=mydisk bs=1 count=2 seek=510 conv=notrunc
```

Then `fdisk mydisk` allowed me to examine semi-valid partition table. I deleted all the partitions and created just one exactly as before. I run `hexdump -C mydisk` and discovered that while the partition table area was altered, the garbage in bootstrap area was still there. **There was no change in the bootstrap code area.**

I haven't tested `fdisk` with MBR containing non-garbage, perfectly sane bootstrap code. I strongly believe the tool doesn't analyze the code. It lets garbage be in this case, so it should do the same with any data.

---

### Conclusion

The `fdisk` behavior depends on the existence of *boot signature* – the value `0xAA55` written as little endian at the very end of the 512-byte MBR.

- When `fdisk` finds the signature, it believes there already is a valid MBR present. It leaves the bootstrap code area untouched, even if some changes in the partition table are made.
- When `fdisk` finds no valid signature, it believes there's no valid MBR, so it creates one while writing the new partition table. In this case the bootstrap code area is zeroed (it won't boot).

**In neither case `fdisk` creates its own bootstrap code that actually boots.**

Comment: Note: I wrote `gdisk`, which is like `fdisk` but for GPT disks. I know of no Linux partitioning tool that writes boot code to the MBR, although there are cases (as in your case #2) in which tools may zero out the MBR code area. I'm less familiar with partitioning tools for other OSes. As you say, there are many partitioning tools, so it would be nearly impossible to say that *none* of them write out boot loader code; even if you examined ten, it's possible that the 11th would do something different. Also note that MBR boot code is becoming less relevant with the switch to EFI-mode booting.

Comment: @RodSmith My answer is about `fdisk` because `fdisk` was explicitly mentioned in the question (although it may refer to `fdisk` for DOS, I'm aware of this). BTW, thank you for your work on `gdisk`.

Comment: no criticism was intended; I just wanted to broaden the scope a bit to point out that, AFAIK, no Linux partitioning software writes boot code to the MBR.

Answer (score 1):

It creates a [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) if none exists, and within it, it creates partition and volume tables for the current partitioning scheme. This information is updated as the scheme changes.

The MBR points to [volume boot records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_boot_record) (VBR; aka the bootsector) for active partitions. When an OS is installed on that partition, it places its bootloader code in the MBR, and its boot sector code within the VBR for its volume. The bootloader then presents bootable VBRs for the user to choose from in the case of a multiboot, or boots to the default VBR in its configuration.

Comment: So does it mean that when an OS is installed it rewrites MBR bootstrap code created earlier by fdisk?

Comment: fdisk does not create the bootstrap code.